# popen is not executing the command line parameters

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to execute the following command via popen but not sure why it is not working and not error message thrown too.

```
import os

class Pabot():

    def run_pabot(self, folderOrSuiteName, tags=None):
        print("pabot --testlevelsplit -r " + folderOrSuiteName + " --i " + tags + " " + folderOrSuiteName + "")
        os.popen("pabot --testlevelsplit -r " + folderOrSuiteName + " --i " + tags + " " + folderOrSuiteName + "")


run = Pabot()
run.run_pabot("o/boo/test.robot", "Sequence_TC1")
```

From print statement:

```
pabot --testlevelsplit -r foo/boo/test.robot --i Sequence_TC1 foo/boo/test.robot
```

Right after execution, the window console gets disappeared.

Note: The same command (from print statement) works fine in commandline.

Any idea why popen does not function in this case?

Comment: When you say "right after execution, the window console get disappeared" do you mean after running python script.py it launches a secondary window then closes it?

Comment: It goes behind pycharm editor.